# Discord bot writing to JSON

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to write something to JSON from my Discord bot however this code

```
from discord.ext import commands
import json

with open("Configs/Premium.json") as f:
    Premium = json.load(f)['serverID']

with open("Configs/Keys.json") as k:
    Keys = json.load(k)


class Redeem:
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def redeem(self, ctx, key):
        if ctx.message.server.id == Premium:
            try:
                await self.client.say('This server already has premium')
            except Exception as error:
                await self.client.say('{}'.format(error))
        else:
            if key in Keys:
                try:
                    with open('Configs/Premium.json', 'a') as lm:
                        json.dump(key, lm)
                        await self.client.say('Premium has been activated for this server')
                except Exception as error:
                    await self.client.say('{}'.format(error))
            else:
                await self.client.say('That key is invalid')


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Redeem(client))
```

Writes to the JSON but makes it like this

```
{
  "serverID": "512338284479774730"
}"KEY USED"
```

However, I want it like this shown below

```
{
  "serverID": "512338284479774730",
  "serverID": "The Key"
}
```

It reads from the file containing the keys ok but wont write the key to the Premium.json

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this, because python dictionaries can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: If your file is just going to be a list of keys/ids, why does it have to be a JSON?  Just have each line be an id.

Comment: I have been using JSON for a long time. I have also tried one lines but my Python skills are bad

Comment: Found another way. Does not matter anymore